# Win32: Anonymous inherited pipes don't close on subprocess exit

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have been attempting to use anonymous pipes to communicate with a spawned subprocess via their stdin and stdout, similar to [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  So far, so good - I communicate with it via WriteFile(), and I read data from it via PeekNamedPipe() and then ReadFile().  Life is good.

However, I'm encountering something distressing - when the subprocess closes unexpectedly, a parent process call to WriteFile() never seems to return any sort of failure state indicating that the pipe has closed, and my parent process happily continues chugging along writing data until I overflow the pipe's internal buffer and block forever.

My setup code looks like this:

```
// Set up pipes
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec_attrs;
memset(&sec_attrs, 0, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
sec_attrs.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sec_attrs.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sec_attrs.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

if (!CreatePipe(&midi_process_in_reader, &midi_process_in_writer, &sec_attrs, 0))
{
    DEBUGOUT("Could not initialize midiproc stdin");
    return false;
}

if (!SetHandleInformation(midi_process_in_writer, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
{
    DEBUGOUT("Could not disinherit midiproc stdin");
    return false;
}

if (!CreatePipe(&midi_process_out_reader, &midi_process_out_writer, &sec_attrs, 0))
{
    DEBUGOUT("Could not initialize midiproc stdout/stderr");
    return false;
}

if (!SetHandleInformation(midi_process_out_reader, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
{
    DEBUGOUT("Could not disinherit midiproc stdin");
    return false;
}

// Launch the subprocess
PROCESS_INFORMATION proc_info;
memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

STARTUPINFO startup_info;
memset(&startup_info, 0, sizeof(startup_info));
startup_info.cb = sizeof(startup_info);
startup_info.hStdInput = midi_process_in_reader;
startup_info.hStdOutput = midi_process_out_writer;
startup_info.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

BOOL ok = CreateProcess(TEXT(module), TEXT(cmdline), NULL, NULL, TRUE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &proc_info);
```

The only difference that I can see between the example and my code is that I don't hook up stderr - I want to keep it around for fprintf debugging.

I am probably going to need to go with some sort of "heartbeat" message in the long run, because the subprocess could become a zombie and be completely alive and keep their handles open but never read off of stdin, which would wedge things in a different way.  However, I want to make sure that I'm not missing something in my understanding of anonymous pipes on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must close `midi_process_in_reader` and `midi_process_out_writer` after calling `CreateProcess()`. Your issue is not because the "inherited pipes don't close on subprocess exit", it is because you forgot to close the pipes in your own process.